# Migrating project from one PC to another for Android Studio

Tags: android

So I created a project in Android Studio in a laptop, and now I want to transfer it to another laptop. I will have to make necessary changes including the project path name. Is there any shorter way which can allow me to do so in a simple manner ? The new device is running on 2.1.2 and the previous device has 2.1.1

Comment: Nothing particular. Copy the project to a folder (or unzip it) on your new computer  and then import it in your workspace. DONE.

Comment: Nah...It doesn't work like that...It can't recognize the 'R' thing. Plus there are rendering problems.

Comment: It really does. I always bring my projects on several machines.

Comment: How do you modify the project path com.project..... ?

Comment: No, that's just the project package name. There is no `com.project....` path on your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the solution to my problem. If one has to transfer project from one PC to another, the versions ( compile sdk version, appcompat version, IDE version, etc) should be matching in the buid.gradle file.

If one is working on multiple devices on a same project, try to keep all the devices at the same version.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't need to do any change in the project . After transfering your project to the new laptop, open Android Studio, open the File/New/ImportProject and select your project. This should be enough.

Comment: Okay, I get the way, but I'm still getting rendering problems.

Comment: To solve rendering problems, check the API level in your android manifest file. Then, go to the problematic layout 'Desgin' tab and serach on the top right corner for the Android symbol. Click on it and change the version of your API.

Comment: There is no API level mentioned in manifest file. It is mentioned in build.gradle file. Changing even that didn't help much.